# Spring Enum list empty in @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below enum with two values, and i have a search api with many fields, One of these fields is a list of `StatusEnum`. So i created a dto that contains this field.

The problem when i send the data the list status is always empty

json exp: `{"status":["En activité"],"startDate":null,"endDate":null}`

```
public enum StatusEnum {

    INACTIVITY, ENDACTIVITY;

    private static Map<String, StatusEnum > namesMap = new HashMap<>(2);

    static {
        namesMap.put("En activité", INACTIVITY);
        namesMap.put("En fin d'activité", ENDACTIVITY);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StatusEnum forValue(String value) {
        return namesMap.get(StringUtils.lowerCase(value));
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String toValue() {
        for (Entry<String, StatusEnum > entry : namesMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == this)
                return entry.getKey();
        }
        return null;
    }

}


@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> search(@RequestBody SearchDTO search) { }

public class SearchDTO {
 
   private Date startDate;
   private Date endDate
   private List<StatusEnum> status;
   //getter and setter
 
}
```

Comment: Before comment, try to return a list of String and in the getStatus() return Arrays.asList(StatusEnum.values());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@JsonCreator
public static StatusEnum forValue(String value) {
    return namesMap.get(StringUtils.lowerCase(value));
}
```

Problem is the usage of #lowerCase in `forValue`!
Your keys in your map aren't lower-cased. That's why `namesMap.get` can't find anything.